# retrieve values by delimiters

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage, delimiter

I have stored a text file into isolated storage, my file is saved in a way of "asdasdasd,asdasdasd", how can I use delimiters to spilt them instead of retrieving the whole string like this:

```
        //Get the Store we created earlier
        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //use a StreamReader to open and read the file           
        StreamReader readFile = null;
        try
        {
            readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SaveFolder\\SavedFile.txt", FileMode.Open, store));
            string fileText = readFile.ReadToEnd();

            //The control txtRead will display the text entered in the file
            textBlock2.Text = fileText;
            readFile.Close();
        }

        catch
        {
            //For now, a simple catch to make sure they created it first
            //we will modify this later
            textBlock2.Text = "Need to create directory and the file first.";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to split string delimited by the specified characters:

```
string fileText = readFile.ReadToEnd();
string[] substrings = fileText.Split(',');
```

Then you can access each substring by an [array index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), for example:

```
textBlock1.Text = substrings[0];
textBlock2.Text = substrings[1];
```

*Note*: It would be better to check if substrings array have at least those two elements.

Comment: how can i use the array of strs?

Comment: @NoobieNeedHelp, it depends what do you want to do with it

Comment: example putting in into a textbox textBlock2.Text = fileText;
                readFile.Close();

Comment: @NoobieNeedHelp so why do you want to split this text?

Comment: in order to put into textblock1 and textblock2

Answer (score 0):

to split them, split the fileText like so:

```
string fileText = readFile.ReadToEnd();

string[] splitText = fileText.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

you now have an array in the splitText. It now contains individual entries

Comment: how can i use the array of spiltText?